# How to do things upon quitting a Qt app

Tags: c++, qt, dll, usb, qt-creator

To my understanding, the following will execute an application which will exit when all associated windows are closed.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication cal(argc, argv); //Application instance

    MainWindow window; //Create window in the stack
    window.show(); //Show the window

    return cal.exec(); //Execute event loop
}
```

This will also quit said application.

```
quitButton = new QPushButton("Quit", this);

connect(quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), QApplication::instance(), SLOT(quit()));
```

How should I go about cleaning up (closing hardware connections and libraries etc.) so that I can be sure everything that needs to happen happens no matter how the app it exited, nor at what point in execution it is exited?

I will have a library open throughout the whole app, and a connection to a USB device at most times. I am able to close this connection easily if the process runs its course, but I want the connection to be closed safely if somebody decides to hit quit or close all the windows before it is done.

Comment: You could inherit from QApplication, and do your cleanup in the destructor. Otherwise, connect to the QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit signal.

Comment: I thought about adding an `aboutToQuit` but thought that this wouldn't work if someone simply closed the windows rather than hitting the quit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication cal(argc, argv);

    // Allocate resources

    int ret = cal.exec(); // start the event loop and wait until it quits

    // Free the resources

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: And this would execute even no matter how the application was stopped?

Comment: If you quit normally - yes.

Comment: Nice and simple. I think this can be prefered over all the Qt hooks, especially if resources are already allocated in the main function

Comment: I think I'll be using this to unload the dll, although I'll probably close the usb connection using @MatthiasB 's suggestion below, to save having to pass identifiers around needlessly

Comment: This is how you'd do it in C, not C++.

Answer (score 2):

There is a virtual function called `closeEvent` for a QWidget (see [Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#closeEvent), which is called when the widgets `close()` operation is called.

Alternatively, if you don't want to have your own Base widget, you can hook yourself to the signal `QApplication::lastWindowClosed` (see [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#lastWindowClosed)). It is emitted when the last visible window of your application closes.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the `close()` operation is called on my window object above whenever the application is quit in any way?

Comment: Only if you quit it in Qt fashion. This includes any Qt function calling `close()`, or using the close button on your window. If you kill your application (e.g in a Debugger), it does not get called.

Comment: Just to clarify when you say close button on window do you mean the red cross in the top corner? I think I'll be fine without handling quitting from debugger, task manager etc.

Comment: Yes. The red X will simply trigger a close event, like your button. For Qt there is not much difference.

Answer (score 1):

The proper C++ way of doing it is:

1. Ensuring that all of your object instances get destructed.
2. Ensuring that any resources you hold are held via [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

Then you don't need to do anything special. As the objects get destructed when `main` returns, things get cleaned up.

For example:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QObject foo;
  QObject * bar = new QObject(&app);
  Widget w;
  w.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

Here, both `foo` and `bar` are properly destructed before `main` returns. Now suppose you hold some non-memory resources, like a file:

```
class Worker : public QObject {
  QFile m_file;
  ...
  void doSomething() {
    if (m_file.open()) {
      ...
    }
    // No file closing!
  }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  Worker foo;
  Widget w;
  w.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

Again, the file gets closed before `main` returns.

That's how RAII works, in a nutshell. If you have your own classes that wrap OS or other resources, simply ensure that such resources are freed when the classes get destructed - and that the classes are *always* destructible (it's always safe to destruct them). My pet peeve is `QThread` - it breaks this expectation, and you have to [implement a wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24869011/1329652) to fix it.

For resources that you need to allocate on the heap, you're supposed to be using smart pointers or `QObject` memory management.

Answer (score 0):

There is a QApplication signal that you can use for cleaning up before the application quits:

`QObject::connect(&app, SIGNAL(aboutToQuit()), &MyCleaner, SLOT(cleanUp()));`

Have fun!